# PHP - Upload files can't seem to work

Tags: php

Pretty new to PHP here. I have copied an online script to attempt to do file uploading, but the script kept showing the message "Could not copy file". I have created the folder "Uploads" within the folder of the script, and I have checked the php.ini file which has allowed File Uploads.

How do I troubleshoot this?

```
<?php
    if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
    copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "Uploads/" ) or 
       die( "Could not copy file!");
}
    else
 {
      die("No file specified!");
 }
?>
```

Note: Followed this tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Comment: do you want to move upload file or your question is something else

Comment: Almost everything is wrong with this. Take a look at [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: just change $_FILES['file']['name'] to $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example on how to upload a file.

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){ 
    $folder = "Uploads/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
    $full_path = $folder.$file; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
        echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";
    } else { 
       echo "upload received! but process failed";
    } 
}else{ 
    echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
}
```

Use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 1):

HTML Part

```
    <form action="" name="entryform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

PHP Part

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  //echo "Error: " . $_FILES['file']['error'] . "<br />";
      echo "<script>alert('Please Select File'); 
                location = 'upload.php';
                </script>";
                exit();
  }
else
  {
 if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
            echo "<script>alert('File Already Exists'); 
                location = 'upload.php';
                </script>";
                exit();
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                  echo "<script>alert('File Uploaded Successfully'); 
                    location = 'upload.php';
                </script>";
                exit();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use **move_uploaded_file** in php

```
move_uploaded_file (  $filename , $destination )
```

refer this [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

COrrect this line copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "Uploads/" ) like copy( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "Uploads/" )